# Is there any advantage in buying a Sidewinder for 32k when you have one for free?

Tags: elite-dangerous

Every player starts with a Sidewinder, and yet there's one for sale for 32k. I wonder why.

Comment: Maybe for when you sold yours and decide you want to buy one again?

Comment: @Chippies isn't more economical to just destroy the current ship instead of spending 32k?

Comment: Not everybody started with a Sidewinder. Some of the [kickstarter backing options](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1461411552/elite-dangerous) had different starting ships. They get the same "free sidewinder or insurance" options when destroyed, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no advantage to it, no. It's a convenience, as you can technically sell your sidewinder, and may wish to buy a new one without having to die.

Comment: Isn't it cheaper to die than to pay 32k for a sidewinder?

Comment: Depends what you're flying in when you die! :)

Comment: If you're in, say, a stock Cobra, it will only cost 19k to get back into it after dying. Even if you want to switch to a stock Sidewinder, you could take the insurance, sell the Cobra for a bit under the 380k purchase price, and basically end up in that Sidewinder and 300k in the bank.

Answer (score 3):

I guess buying one for 32k means you could have more than one sidewinder, each kitted out for different purposes. (e.g. mining, combat, trade, etc.)

If you have enough in-game experience to care about having multiple specialised ships, then you probably have enough money to do this with better ships than a sidewinder.

But maybe even then, you might want to have a fleet of sidewinders available for use because they are so relatively cheap, and hence you don't care so much if you lose them. They are almost disposable.

Answer (score 0):

The generic Sidewinder is a free, if you choose it after dying.  However, you may want to pick up a Sidewinder as a second ship (for example if you don't want to risk your Anaconda in Anarchy space).  In that instance, you will have to pay the purchase cost of a second ship.

Answer (score 0):

Sidewinders can be convenient to get from place A to place B safely.

If you are in a Type 9 at Sol, and have a Vulture in Zaonce and want to get to it to do some bounty-hunting you can buy a (disposable) Sidewinder to get to your Vulture.

Flying in your Type 9 means running the risk of losing it (and it's cargo) and therefore lots of money.

Using the Sidewinder is risk-free because even you get blown up, you get a new one back.

Consider them risk-free shuttles (and don't upgrade them).

Come to think of it; what's stopping a player from selling his optional modules (like weapons), self-destructing, getting the free Sidewinder, and repeating? Did I just find an extremely slow exploit?

Comment: The modules that come with your ship when you buy it are 'loaned', so you don't get any money for selling them.